# RegEx " " to ' ' with conditions

Tags: regex, typescript

I need to make replacement with quotes "" in a string.

```
string = `bike "car" bus "'airplane'" "bike" "'train'"`
```

1. if word inside " " need to replace for ' ' ("car" -> 'car')
2. if brackets inside brackets " ' ' " -> remove outside brackets (" 'airplane' " -> 'airplane')

So in the end I should have

```
 `bike 'car' bus 'airplane' 'bike' 'train'`
```

I've found similar regex `/(?=(?:"[^"]*?"[^"]*)+$)"([^"']*?)"/gm` but it doesn't work exactly as I needed, it doesn't work for second condition

```
const regex = /(?=(?:"[^"]*?"[^"]*)+$)"([^"']*?)"/gm;
const str =  `bike "car" bus "'airplane'" "bike" "'train'"`;
const subst = `'$1'`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
// bike 'car' bus "'airplane'" 'bike' "'train'"
```

I could do it by adding two more replace, but don't think that it's look good
Here my result

```
const result = str.replace(regex, subst).replace(/"'/g, "'").replace(/'"/g, "'"); //found if string has " ' and replace to ', and same for ' " -> '
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example data, you might use 2 capture groups and use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with a callback checking for the value of one of the groups.

Then return the matched value between single quotes.

```
"'(.*?)'"|"([^"\s]*)"
```

The pattern matches:

- `"'(.*?)'"` Capture 0+ times any char in **group 1** between `"'` and `'"`
- `|` Or
- `"([^"'\s]+)"` Capture 0+ times any char other than `"` or a whitespace char in **group 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zmBNOe/1)

```js
const regex = /"'(.*?)'"|"([^"\s]*)"/g;
const string = `bike "car" bus "'airplane'" "bike" "'train'"`;
const result = string.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2) => g1 ? `'${g1}'` : `'${g2}'`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The @The fourth bird answer is good using a callback for replace. Here is another version with two consecutive replaces without callbacks:

```js
const str = `bike "car" bus "'airplane'" "bike" "'train'"`;
let result = str.replace(/"'(.*?)'"/g, "'$1'").replace(/"([^"\s]*)"/g, "'$1'");
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
bike 'car' bus 'airplane' 'bike' 'train'
```

Explanation:

- search 1: `/"'(.*?)'"/` - non-greedy scan for `"'`...`'"`

  - replace: `"'$1'"` - replace with single quotes
- search 2: `/"([^"\s]*)"/` - non-greedy scan for `"`...`"`

  - replace: `"'$1'"` - replace with single quotes